# Multi-word search causes exploding indexes?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to enable multi-word search with google app engine. However there appears an error message in the log as follows

```
The index for this query is not ready to serve. See the Datastore Indexes page in the Admin Console.
This query needs this index:
- kind: A
  properties:
  - name: __searchable_text_index
  - name: __searchable_text_index
  - name: published
  - name: modified
    direction: desc
```

The actual query I run is

```
entities = A.all().filter("modified >", timeline).filter("published =", True).filter("modified <=", bookmark ).order("-modified").search(self.request.get('q')).fetch(PAGESIZE+1)
```

It works with one word but for phrases with 2 or more words it fails. Do you have any idea how I should do it?
Thanks

Comment: How long have you waited for the index to build?  What is the status of this index on the Datastore Indexes page?

Comment: It builds the index for 2 __searchable_text_index which then appears in error state when built and needs to get removed. How can I proceed when the index needed gets error state?

Comment: If it is in error state, use appcfg to vacuum it.  You can try to build it again, but you may need to wait for the new zig-zag merges to go online so you do not need that index.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I now try build it anew hoping it will work thanking you for inspecting the matter. It seems a bit odd needing to build a new index just for a multi-word search. Does it mean I need new index for 3 words also or that this will get resolved with an engine update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this leads to an 'exploding' index, because the number of index entries is proportional to the square of the number of words in the entity's list.

If you drop the order and inequality filters, your query will be satisfiable using the built in merge join strategy, and you can sort the results in memory.

Comment: Thanks Nick! It works dropping the order and inequality filters. Sorting is quite simple inmemory now leading to question how I do something like filter("modified >", timeline) and fetch(PAGESIZE+1) inmemory.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to wait for Google to come up with a full-text search service, which they finally have now. Still eager to learn how well it performs.